# Search for multiple strings at the same time

Tags: shell, unix, search, grep

After running some commands I get a text file that look like this:

```
TACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCA
AATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAG
AGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAA
AATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAG
CTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAAT
AGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAAT
```

This text file change each time, and I want to search for all of this strings in another file that contains thousands of lines. Remember the strings are not the same, they change each time, so I cannot just copy and paste them, and then use the grep command for the search.
I tried to use the grep command with the file (`grep -f test.txt all_lines.txt`) but it only search for the first line. I have many of this files so I need a very efficient way. How can I do this?

Comment: see if you system has `fgrep`, then use it as you indicated, with `-f ...` file args. Also check you `man grep`, I thought you need `-F` AND `-f` to read from a file. Finally, I kind of remember something about the listFile needing to be sorted. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following `awk` one-liner. Since you haven't posted data from the file you want to check against the answer may need to be modified to suit your needs:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { lines[$0]++; next }
{ 
  for(line in lines) {
    if(index($0,line)>0) {
      print $0 " <===> " line
    }
  }
}' smallfile bigfile
```

Here is a small test:

```
$ cat f1
ba
cat
bee
```

```
$ cat f2
caterpillar
balloon
beautiful
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}{for(x in a){if(index($0,x)>0){print $0" <===> "x}}}' f1 f2
caterpillar <===> cat
balloon <===> ba
```

You don't really need the `<===>` in the command. That was just for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Many a times we are called to search a string, but we have no idea where it may be lurking.

```
# find . -type f -exec grep "string or options" / dev/null {} \;
```

Normally using only:

```
 # find . -type f -exec grep "string or options" {} \;
```

produces the target string, but you will have no clue as to where it is located. Remember the when grep'ing against multiple files the file name will be listed before the match.

```
$grep there *

foo: I found the target here
bar: You are there
```

In our find command we use `/dev/null` as a file to search against, since we know the search will always fail if the string is found in `"{}";` then filename is printed.